# Git merge in a pull request on Github

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I have a branch called `hotfix` (branched from the `master` branch) for which I opened a **pull request** on Github. The request page said that the `hotfix` branch is not up to date and provided me an option to `Update Branch`. On clicking this option, it says `Merging branch 'master' into hotfix`.

So I just wanted to ask that the `master` branch will remain as is, right? The wording above is a little ambiguous to me. If not, what is the right way to do it on the Github UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language "merging X into Y" means that any new commits which are present on X, but aren't on Y will be added after all the commits currently on Y.  Or, if you currently have:

```
master:    A - B - C - D - E
               \
hotfix:          X - Y - Z
```

After merging `master` into `hotfix`, you'll have:

```
master:    A - B - C - D - E
               \           \
hotfix:          X - Y - Z - C - D - E
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the confirmation what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is equivalent to the following set of commands, if you were trying to do this locally:

```
git checkout hotfix  // hotfix is behind master by some number of commits       
git merge master
```

Which just synchronizes your hotfix branch, but leaves the master branch intact. It will grab the changes from master, which aren't in your branch, into your branch:

https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the master branch will remain as is. It is just your branch "hotfix" which is again updated with the latest master branch code.